# JS - dates in array, link building

Tags: javascript, jquery, calendar

I'm looking for a way to add a working link to the eventName.
If I add a link directly in the code, it will be displayed **as text, not as link.**
Do I have to write a completely new function here or is somewhere simple trick enough?
I will be grateful for your response.

```
!function () {
    var data = [
        {eventName: '<a href="#">EventName</a>', calendar: 'Work', color: 'orange', eventTime: moment("2021-12-22")},
        {eventName: '<a href="#">EventName</a>', calendar: 'Work', color: 'orange', eventTime: moment("2021-12-02")},
        {eventName: '<a href="#">EventName</a>', calendar: 'Other', color: 'green', eventTime: moment("2021-12-09")}
    ];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right around line 303 you have this:

```
  var span = createElement('span', '', ev.eventName);
```

The default behavior of that 3rd argument is to set it's content as `text` element. You can force it to render the content as HTML with this additional line.

```
  var span = createElement('span', '');
  span.innerHTML= ev.eventName;
```

Example: https://codepen.io/javacado/pen/bGoogYg?editors=1111

Comment: It was really helpful and innovative

Answer (score 1):

You are creating the event as a span, so it just prints out the anchor tag as text

On your `Calendar.prototype.renderEvents` function, you should create an anchor tag and set its href

```
var a = createElement("a", "", ev.eventName);
a.href = "#";
```

Instead of

```
var span = createElement("span", "", ev.eventName);
```